# How to handle multiple values ​to one parameter in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am passing multiple values ​​to one parameter in the query string like this:

`https://localhost:44303/?searchString=A&searchString=B`

I have some code that handles this. But if I pass 2 or more values, then it simply returns nothing. And if I pass 1 value, then it works as it should

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string[] searchString)
       {
           
           ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;


           var cosmetics = from s in db.Cosmetics
                          select s;
           foreach(string ss in searchString)
           {
               
                   cosmetics = cosmetics.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(ss));
               
           }

           return View(await cosmetics.ToListAsync());
       }
```

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
foreach(string ss in searchString)
           {
               
                   cosmetics = cosmetics.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(ss));
               
           }
```

to

```
var list = new List<cosmetic>();
            foreach (string ss in searchString)
            {
                List<cosmetic> ll = cosmetics.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(ss)).ToList();
                list.AddRange(ll);

            }
```

Update:

Change

```
return View(await cosmetics.ToListAsync());
```

to

```
return View(list);
```

**Update2:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string[] searchString)
        {

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
            var cosmetics = from s in db.Cosmetics
                            select s;
            if (searchString.Length != 0)
            {
                var list = new List<cosmetic>();
                foreach (string ss in searchString)
                {
                    List<cosmetic> ll = cosmetics.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(ss)).ToList();
                    list.AddRange(ll);

                }
                return View(list);
            }

            return View(await cosmetics.ToListAsync());
        }
```

Comment: Checked does not work too. Maybe there are some other ways to accept multiple values ​​for one parameter?

Comment: I have updated my answer,you can create a new list<cosmetic>called list,and then select  cometics Name contain ss,and push the cometics to the list.The list is what you want.

Comment: Yes it worked. But I had to change the method from async to simple. How can I pass this list to View() async?

Comment: I updated my answer.You can use `return View(list);`

Comment: Yes, I did that before. But now all goods are not displayed. only products whose name I passed to the query string is displayed. And I need to display all the products, and when passing the value to the query string, only the products that I passed to the query string are displayed

Comment: See my newest answer(Update2).